# How come jQuery.load() can work Cross-Domain if the URL has "just one HTML line"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On my website, I'm attempting to code a JavaScript script that, upon a button being clicked, scrapes data from the HTML source of some websites and displays the parsed/cleaned data on my site.

Upon reading [TutorialsPoint's JQuery - Ajax page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm), which showcases the jQuery.load() method,

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#driver").click(function(event){
           $('#stage').load('/jquery/result.html');
        });
     });
</script>
```

I decided to try it on my site. I changed the URL from the relative one to the absolute one -- "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/result.html" -- and to my surprise, it is actually functioning (click *EXTRACT DATA*). This contradicts my understanding, upon reading dozens of SO threads, as well as the jQuery.load() API, that the HTTP request would be subject to the Same-Origin-Policy.

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol. ~[API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

When I change the URL to things like http://google.com/ or http://www.example.com/ the script doesn't function.

A line on the aforereferenced tutorial page caught my eye:

> Here load() initiates an Ajax request to the specified URL /jquery/result.html file. After loading this file, all the content would be populated inside  tagged with ID stage. **Assuming, our /jquery/result.html file has just one HTML line**

How come load() works, across domains, if the HTML file at the specified URL has solely one line?

Comment: It depends on the server. If the server allows: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then it works.

Comment: Downvoters explain, please. I don't see anything innately wrong with my question.

Comment: Hey, it could be because their vote is locked. I edited the question and added a vote as well. Soon it will go off. It's 0 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about the files or structure. It's about enabling [**Cross Origin Request Sharing**](https://enable-cors.org/). If the concerned server, or the request has the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will enable the AJAX to fetch files from cross-domain as well.

Indeed, sending an HTTP GET request via [Hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it), for example, confirms that the header is present.

[image: Request picture]

Answer (score 2):

Internally `load()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax`, the code for `load()` is

```
function load(url, params, callback) {
    // ... some checks and stuff
        jQuery.ajax({
            // settings
        }).done(function (responseText) {
            self.html(selector ?
            jQuery("<div>").append(jQuery.parseHTML(responseText)).find(selector) : responseText);
        }).complete(callback && function (jqXHR, status) {
            self.each(callback, response || [jqXHR.responseText, status, jqXHR]);
        });
    }
    return this;
}
```

In this case the server is returning the correct headers for a [CORS requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), if you look at the request, the response headers include

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

meaning it allows requests from different origins, so it has nothing to do with `load()` at all, any ajax request would work fine to that URL, as it's not subject to the same-origin policy

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP
>   headers that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are
>   permitted to read that information using a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was no way the function could be violating the Same-Origin Policy.

Sending a GET request to the HTML page via [Hurl.It](https://www.hurl.it/) yielded the reason:

> GET http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/result.html
>
> HEADERS
>
> ...
>
> *Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> ...

Comment: Yup... That's what I added in my answer... `:)`